# vibration and sound won't be played

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    CharSequence tickerText = "HI!";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.droid,
            tickerText, when);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

for some reason - none of the flags really applied except for the auto cancel.

No vibration, no sound, no lights.

What can cause this?
I tried in 3.1 & in 2.2.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```